# markdown-it alternative that creates dom elements instead of rendering HTML text

Tags: javascript, typescript, markdown

I'm currently using markdown-it for my web-extensions to display translatable tutorials & changelogs. But Mozilla has safety checks in place telling me that the use of `innerHTML` is unsafe. So I'm wondering if there is a JavaScript (ideally TypeScript) markdown library that creates dom-elements rather than rendering HTML text?

Comment: [Try using **jQuery**](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: You can create DOM elements with the Web API, you don't need a library.

Comment: I know how to create dom elements.. My problem is, that the library "markdown-it" only spits out HTML code rather than new dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the issue that works without using eval:

```
// This was the old code:
container.innerHTML = md.render(value);

// This is the new code:
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const doc = domParser.parseFromString(md.render(value), 'text/html');
removeAllChildren(container);
for(let i=0; i<doc.body.childNodes.length; i++)
    container.appendChild(doc.body.childNodes[i]);
```